# Unable to compile C++ program with tf2_ros header inclusion

Tags: cmake, c++14, ros, ros2

I have installed ros2 dashing diademata. I wrote a ROS2 node using C++14. I would like to read `static_tf` by creating a buffer and `TransformListener`

I am getting the following error when I include, `#include "tf2_ros/buffer.h"` If I do not include, I do not get any error.

The error is as follows

```
In file included from /opt/ros/dashing/include/tf2/LinearMath/Vector3.h:21:0,
                 from /opt/ros/dashing/include/tf2/LinearMath/Matrix3x3.h:19,
                 from /opt/ros/dashing/include/tf2/LinearMath/Transform.h:21,
                 from /opt/ros/dashing/include/tf2/buffer_core.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/dashing/include/tf2_ros/buffer_interface.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/dashing/include/tf2_ros/buffer.h:35,
                 from /module/src/example/include/example/example.h:17,
                 from /module/src/example/src/example.cpp:7:
/opt/ros/dashing/include/tf2/LinearMath/Scalar.h: In function ‘tf2Scalar tf2Log(tf2Scalar)’:
/opt/ros/dashing/include/tf2/LinearMath/Scalar.h:187:66: error: expression cannot be used as a function
 TF2SIMD_FORCE_INLINE tf2Scalar tf2Log(tf2Scalar x) { return log(x); }
```

`CMakeLists.txt` is as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(curb_odometry)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wunused-parameter)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(nav_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2_ros REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2 REQUIRED)
find_package(message_filters REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
include_directories(include 
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  ${tf2_ros_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  ${rclcpp_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  ${sensor_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  ${geometry_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  ${nav_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR} 
  ${message_filters_INCLUDE_DIR}
)
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_executable(example src/example.cpp src/curb_detection.cpp src/curb_odometry.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example ${Boost_LIBRARIES}  )
target_include_directories(example PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
ament_target_dependencies(
  example
  "rclcpp"
  "sensor_msgs"
  "geometry_msgs"
  "nav_msgs"
  "std_msgs"
  "boost"
  "message_filters"
  "geometry2"
  "tf2_ros"
  "tf2"
)
install(TARGETS example
  EXPORT export_${PROJECT_NAME}
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})
if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()
ament_package()
```

Looks like the error is coming from tf library. Any help in this regard will be appreciable.

Comment: If you compile only `add_executable(example src/example.cpp)` with `example.cpp` containing only one line which is `#include "tf2_ros/buffer.h"` ?

Comment: What happens if you put `find_package(tf2 REQUIRED)` before `find_package(tf2_ros REQUIRED)`?